# Call function after DataTable is filtered

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have DataTable filled with js-switches, here's the code:

```
$('#bandsTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        'type': 'GET',
        'url': 'myUrl',
        'data': function (d) {
            d._token = Laravel.csrfToken;
        }
    },
    columns: [
        {
            title: "Number",
            data: "number"
        },
        {
            title: "Privileged",
            data: "privileged"
        }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            render: function (data) {
                var checked = data ? 'checked' : '';

                return '' +
                    '<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="schedule_deactivation" ' +
                    checked + ' data-switchery="false" style="display: none;"> \n';

            },
            targets: 1
        }
    ],
    order: [[0, 'asc']],
    fnRowCallback: function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        nRow.className = "band-row";
        nRow.setAttribute("data-band", aData.number);
        return nRow;
    },
    responsive: true
});
```

When I filter result's they're displayed correctly, but I don't see checkboxes generated, I can type JS from the console and it works when I type:

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function (html) {
    var switchery = new Switchery(html, {
        color: '#26B99A',
        secondaryColor: '#ff7a77'
    });
});
```

but I don't know when I should call this code. I have no idea about DataTable lifecycle and where should I inject the code. Should it be some callback defined by DataTables or something else?

Comment: try this  `$('#bandsTable').on('draw.dt',   function () { eventFired( 'Page' ); } ).DataTable()` https://datatables.net/reference/event/

Comment: you should load js switch script again on ajax success because of use with serverside processing, ajax call will break all old custom script binding in data table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the documentation on the below link for more, but the code should work as follows:

```
$('#bandsTable').on('draw.dt', function () { 
   var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
   elems.forEach(function (html) {
    var switchery = new Switchery(html, {
        color: '#26B99A',
        secondaryColor: '#ff7a77'
    });
   });
});
```

Link:
 https://datatables.net/reference/event/